# Meteor sendVerificationEmail sends email with `/#/` in it

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm sending email verification link to user with `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail`.
But it contain's `#` like this `http://localhost:3000/#/verify-email/03A10mcEn23kObnBOWgoEqyRIdmwuHKJJ_Yi3QGBdUC`.

On the flow router side, this causes me to be unable to catch this url with neither of these routes `'/verify-email/:token'`, `'/#/verify-email/:token'`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can modify verification email link

```
Accounts.urls.verifyEmail = function (token) {
  return Meteor.absoluteUrl('verify-email/' + token);
};
```

this will give you the link

```
http:localhost:3000/verify-email/somerandomtoken
```

using your route you can catch this url

Comment: I have completely missed that on docs. I can't find it. Can you give link to the doc about this?

Comment: @DulguunOtgon It used to be in 1.2 docs, it is removed in 1.3